# Generating a pdf in Ruby app on *a Linux server*: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: ruby, linux, pdf, pdfkit, wicked-pdf

When trying to generate a pdf * on a server* in Ruby/Rack app using gem "pdfkit", "~> 0.8.2" gem:

```
kit = PDFKit.new("some string here", 
                  page_size: paper_size, 
                  # ..............
                  zoom: 1)

fl = kit.to_file("/tmp/test123.pdf")
```

I have this error:

```
  qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display                                                                                                   
  Could not connect to any X display.
```

How to fix it? I've tried

```
xhost +
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

Of course, there's no physical display on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You should install X screen drivers on remote server.

I had similar problems with X display when tried to render pdf using `wkhtml2pdf` lib on Ubuntu server (in docker container, actually).

In my case problem was solved by installation of several libs:

```
apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
xfonts-base \
xfonts-75dpi \
xserver-common
```

General is `xserver-common`. Maybe it will help.

Good luck!